# Load function when partial view calls

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

From main page submit  i m calling partial view sub page1 , same time i need to update one image in main page.

```
 <div>
  @if (Model.ReportViewFilteringResult !=null)
  { 
   here i need to call main page script function to update Image or data in    main page view          
   }
 </div>
```

is it  possible ? how ?

Comment: How you are calling partial view? button click?

Comment: actually in sidebar page1, page2,page3 is there and content area.In page 1 partial view button clicks page2 paritial opens with data. submit click only. same time i need to update content area also. problem is i can either  call partial view of page2 or i can pass json result ,show main area. both is not working.

Comment: The above code , i m getting model result . how can i call main page function  here.   @using (Ajax.BeginForm("FilterReportByAreaData", "Report", new AppAjaxOptions()
    { }  like this way

Comment: Put your image also in another partial value and load it everytime. does it make sense?